# Trying to post data with Request NPM from NodeJS to localhost (Loopback Swagger API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, loopback

When I try to post an instance to loopback from within nodejs using this code I don't get any errors but I don't get any data posted either?

```
//NPM Package (request)
var request = require('request'); 

// Address of Loopback API on the same server
var api = "http://localhost:3000/api/devices"; 

//JSON Construction
var deviceInstance = {
     "manufacturer": "manufacturer",
     "model": "model"
   //etc
}

// NPM (request)
request({
   url: api,
   method: "POST",
   headers: {"Accept: application/json"},
   json: true,
   body: deviceInstance
}, function (error, response, body) {
      if(error) {
        console.log('error: '+ error);
      } else {
        console.log('document saved to api')
        console.log(body);
        console.log(response);
      }
});

process.exit();
```

I'm not getting any response or erros from the server which is the same machine. If I try the same call in postman (windows app) it actually creates an instance in the API so why isn't my local node connecting to the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why **process.exit()** ?

Calling process.exit() will force the process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending.

Comment: [Source](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code). You can resolve this by moving `process.exit()` to inside the `request` callback

Comment: This is a script to insert thousands of items into loopback and once it's done I want the node to stop. I can't move process.exit into the callback because this code is in a loop.

Comment: But I can't get this one test item to even post from nodejs

Comment: Here's the weird thing the code kinda works with postman but not from within nodejs, with postman I get a post in loopback but I don't see the manufacturer or model data just a new Id in loopback api

Answer (score 1):

### **What happens and why**

The behaviour you are seeing is because of the **asynchronous** nature of Javascript.

Your code, from top to bottom, **starts** the POST request, and then calls `process.exit()` before the request is done, which gives the behaviour you are seeing and "breaks" your code.

From there you have two solutions:

### Calling process.exit() in the callback of the request

```
//NPM Package (request)
var request = require('request'); 

// Address of Loopback API on the same server
var api = "http://localhost:3000/api/devices"; 

//JSON Construction
var deviceInstance = {
     "manufacturer": "manufacturer",
     "model": "model"
   //etc
}

// NPM (request)
request({
   url: api,
   method: "POST",
   headers: {"Accept: application/json"},
   json: true,
   body: deviceInstance
}, function (error, response, body) {
      if(error) {
        console.log('error: '+ error);
      } else {
        console.log('document saved to api')
        console.log(body);
        console.log(response);
      }
      //request is done, we can safely exit
      process.exit();
});
```

Calling the `exit()` function in the callback of your `request` will effectively assure you that the POST request is done and you can exit safely.

### Removing process.exit() altogether

Fact is, you didn't need to exit manually: any Node process exits on its own once the **event loop** is empty. In other words, once no further task is scheduled for the process, node exits the process on its own.

You can find more information about this in the official documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit

Answer (score 0):

`request` needs a callback :

```
request({
  url: api + "Devices",
  method: "POST",
  headers: "Accept: application/json",
  json: true,
  body: JSONParent
}, (err, result, body) => {
  // do your stuffs with the results
});
```

Comment: same problem no response from the server I've updated my question to show how I am doing error reporting. currently nothing comes back after the request even though I specify to console.log the response, body and any errors.